# SQLite3 serial type wasn't incremented

Tags: python, sqlite

I was creating a database by using SQLite3.
and my python version is 2.7.5.

Before creating a database I simply created example database and tested it whether it will function well or not.
and It failed that the `id` wasn't incremented even I 
declared it as a `serial` type.

I created simple database:

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('sample.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE sample(id serial,test real)""")
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO sample(test) VALUES(?)""",(3,))
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO sample(test) VALUES(?)""",(6,))
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO sample(test) VALUES(?)""",(8,))
con.commit()
```

Then I fetched all data:

```
data = cur.execute("""SELECT * from sample""")
t = data.fetchall()

In [33]: t
Out[33]: [(None, 3.0), (None, 6.0), (None, 8.0)]
```

I expected this:`Out[33]: [(1, 3.0), (2, 6.0), (3, 8.0)]`
However, As you can see, all of the `id` element was `None`

How can I solve this problem ?
I know I can do by just incrementing a variable and Insert it.
like this:

```
id += 1
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE sample(id serial,test real)""")
id += 1
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO sample(test) VALUES(?)""",(3,))
id += 1
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO sample(test) VALUES(?)""",(6,))
```

However, isn't this awful ? I don't want to do it.
I'd like to make my code clear and smart.

Comment: Where did you get the 'serial' type *from*? There is no such keyword in SQLite.

Comment: Really ? I found it in the internet also in a BOOK!
hmmm, then is there any substitute that does the same what I wanted?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no `serial` data type in SQLite. The correct way to create the table is with [AUTOINCREMENT](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) in SQLite:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sample ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
                      test REAL);
```

Comment: Thank you very much it is helpful!
but what does `NOT NULL` do ?
Could I omit it ? or an Error will occur ?

Comment: NOT NULL just means, that this field is required. And, yes, you can omit it.

Comment: Does `NOT NULL` *do* anything on an autoincrement column?

Answer (score 6):

You'd need to mark a column as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` to get auto-incrementation behaviour.

The difference between those two types is subtle; the latter form will never reuse IDs. See the [ROWID and the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) documentation.

Comment: uh, now I understand what you mean! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Sorry, you can mark only *one* answer as accepted, not both. :-)

Comment: At first, I couldn't understand your answer well, but after Mr.Alexander Zhukov's answer and I tried to do what he told me. 
and then eventually, I understood what you meant also. so I marked his answer as accepted sine It was the first answer I understood.